# XhrReceivingTransportHandler:Failed to read message

Tags: java, jackson, stomp, spring-websocket, sockjs

Getting the following exception when spring falls back to XHR rather than websocket connection.

```
22:27:13,340||ERROR|XhrReceivingTransportHandler:|Failed to read message
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input
    at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@6aded705; line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:164) ~[jackson-databind-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:3036) ~[jackson-databind-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2978) ~[jackson-databind-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2144) ~[jackson-databind-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.frame.Jackson2SockJsMessageCodec.decodeInputStream(Jackson2SockJsMessageCodec.java:67) ~[spring-websocket-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.handler.XhrReceivingTransportHandler.readMessages(XhrReceivingTransportHandler.java:41) ~[spring-websocket-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.handler.AbstractHttpReceivingTransportHandler.handleRequestInternal(AbstractHttpReceivingTransportHandler.java:56) [spring-websocket-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.handler.AbstractHttpReceivingTransportHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHttpReceivingTransportHandler.java:48) [spring-websocket-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.TransportHandlingSockJsService.handleTransportRequest(TransportHandlingSockJsService.java:306) [spring-websocket-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.support.AbstractSockJsService.handleRequest(AbstractSockJsService.java:433) [spring-websocket-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.support.SockJsHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(SockJsHttpRequestHandler.java:132) [spring-websocket-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
```

Comment: Have you find any solution to this issue? I've been having the same problem since I put a Apache as load balancer in front of my JBoss Server. Without the Apache the error does not happen.

Comment: Yes, this is a problem with Apache httpd. It messed around with the incoming headers. We switched to nginx and the problem was resolved.